# no such table: AspNetUsers

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6

When I dropped Database to clear up previous data, and Update-Database, I got an error: SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AspNetUsers'.

Any solutions?

Full error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      INSERT INTO "ef_temp_AspNetUsers" ("Id", "AccessFailedCount", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Email", "EmailConfirmed", "LockoutEnabled", "LockoutEnd", "NormalizedEmail", "NormalizedUserName", "PasswordHash", "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "Photo", "SecurityStamp", "TwoFactorEnabled", "UserName")
      SELECT "Id", "AccessFailedCount", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Email", "EmailConfirmed", "LockoutEnabled", "LockoutEnd", "NormalizedEmail", "NormalizedUserName", "PasswordHash", "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "Photo", "SecurityStamp", "TwoFactorEnabled", "Username"
      FROM "AspNetUsers";
Failed executing DbCommand (1ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
INSERT INTO "ef_temp_AspNetUsers" ("Id", "AccessFailedCount", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Email", "EmailConfirmed", "LockoutEnabled", "LockoutEnd", "NormalizedEmail", "NormalizedUserName", "PasswordHash", "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "Photo", "SecurityStamp", "TwoFactorEnabled", "UserName")
SELECT "Id", "AccessFailedCount", "ConcurrencyStamp", "Email", "EmailConfirmed", "LockoutEnabled", "LockoutEnd", "NormalizedEmail", "NormalizedUserName", "PasswordHash", "PhoneNumber", "PhoneNumberConfirmed", "Photo", "SecurityStamp", "TwoFactorEnabled", "Username"
FROM "AspNetUsers";
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AspNetUsers'.
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.GetStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(Relenter code hereationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.MigrationCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: AspNetUsers'.
```

Comment: Table does not exist, What is not clear?

Comment: I dropped DB and updated database, so table should be created. Or Am I wrong?

Comment: What is this, code-first?

Comment: No, I used Db-first. The database worked earlier (also .NET users), but then I decided to recreate it.

Comment: you need to look into your DB. This is not a code issue